# Making Scene at editor mode

Tags: unity, c#, scene

On Button click at **editor mode** I am trying to make a scene of selected Hierarchy game-object but the problem is as i click the button new scene
     become upon and I lost the scene where i were selected the Game-object. My code given below:

```
 if (GUILayout.Button("Generate Scene"))
        {
            Scene newScene = EditorSceneManager.NewScene(NewSceneSetup.DefaultGameObjects);;
            SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(Selection.activeGameObject, newScene);
            EditorApplication.SaveScene("Assets/RegionScene/" + gameObjectSelected[gameObjectSelected.Count - 1].name + ".unity"); //newScene

        }
```

Comment: ...and what would you like to happen instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [NewSceneMode.Additive](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.NewSceneMode.html) to create the new scene without discarding the currently open scene(s).

Pass this as the second parameter of the [NewScene()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.NewScene.html) method.